# Diffraction peaks and Miller indices

Tags: optics, condensed-matter, diffraction, crystals

How do we find out if a diffraction peak is observable using miller-indices?

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that we don't answer homework or worked example type questions. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework/exercise questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).

Comment: I hope thats better?

Comment: use the Braggs relation with d expressed in terms of (h,k,l) and try to index the maxima using info about the crystal lattice type.

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking about is the [systematic absences](http://reference.iucr.org/dictionary/Systematic_absences) that occur in X-ray diffration when the structure factor is zero. This is too big a subject to do it justice in an answer here, but any book on crystallography will cover the subject or [there are many descriptions online](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=x%20ray%20diffraction%20systematic%20absences).

The systematic absences occur when atoms inside the unit cell scatter X-rays and this scattering interferes destructively with the scattering from the lattice. Calculating the structure factors can be a bit involved, though in simple lattices like BCC the calculations are simplified due to the symmetry. For example in the BCC lattice the scattering from the plane $(h,k,l)$ is missing if $h+k+l$ is odd. In the FCC lattice the only planes that scatter are the ones that have $h$, $k$ and $l$ all odd or all even.